# File API / Добавление описания к загружаемому фото

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не происходит обновление текста в параграфе с  `class="table_casino__uploadImg_text"` после того, как добавляется фотография в input ?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function uploadPhoto() {

    var file_api = (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) ? true : false;

    $(".table_casino__uploadImg_upload").change(function() {

      var file_name;
      if (file_api && ($(this)[0].files[0])) {
        file_name = ($(this))[0].files[0].name;
      } else {
        file_name = $(this).val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", '');
      }

      if (!file_name.length)
        return;

      if ($(this).prev(".file_upload__text").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).prev(".file_upload__text").text(file_name);
      }

    }).change();


    $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".table_casino__uploadImg_upload").triggerHandler("change");
    });

  }
  uploadPhoto();

}
```

```css
.table_casino__uploadImg_lable {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 264px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 264px
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_upload {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(2);
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="table_casino__uploadImg_lable"><img class="table_casino__uploadImg_image" src="http://vseavtomaty.loc/wp-content/plugins/casino-table/img/casinos/no-image.jpg" alt="name"><p class="table_casino__uploadImg_text">Файл не выбран</p><input class="table_casino__uploadImg_upload" type="file" name="fileImg[]" accept="image/jpeg,image/png"></label>
```

Я хочу вместо текста "Фаил не выбран" получать название фаила и его текущий адресс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не происходит обновление текста в параграфе с class="table_casino__uploadImg_text" после того как добавляется фотография в input ?

Вы его забыли добавить...

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function uploadPhoto() {

    var file_api = (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) ? true : false;

    $(".table_casino__uploadImg_upload").change(function() {

      var file_name;
      //----------------------------------------------------------------
      // Заменил ваше на $(this).prop('files')[0]
      //----------------------------------------------------------------
      if (file_api && ($(this).prop('files')[0])) {
        file_name = ($(this)).prop('files')[0].name;
        console.log(file_name, $(this).prop('files')[0]); // Диббаг
      } else {
        file_name = $(this).val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", '');
      }

      if (!file_name.length)
        return;

      if ($(this).prev(".file_upload__text").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).prev(".file_upload__text").text(file_name);
      }
      // Забыли добавить?
      $('.table_casino__uploadImg_text').text(file_name);

    }).change();


    $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".table_casino__uploadImg_upload").triggerHandler("change");
    });

  }
  uploadPhoto();

}
```

```css
.table_casino__uploadImg_lable {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 264px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 264px
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: none;
}

.table_casino__uploadImg_upload {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%) scale(2);
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="table_casino__uploadImg_lable">
<img class="table_casino__uploadImg_image" src="http://vseavtomaty.loc/wp-content/plugins/casino-table/img/casinos/no-image.jpg" alt="name">

<p class="table_casino__uploadImg_text">Файл не выбран</p>
<input class="table_casino__uploadImg_upload" type="file" name="fileImg[]" accept="image/jpeg,image/png"></label>
```